# Using Regex, is it possible to use an expression such as 'Followed by' or 'Preceded by'

Tags: java, regex

I have the following expression where i want to extract an identifier that is 12 digits long:

```
([12]\d{3})(\d{6})(\d{2})
```

This works fine if the string is in the following format:

```
ABCD123456789101
123456789101
```

When it gets a string like the following, how does it know which 12 digits to match on:

```
ABCD1234567894837376383439434343232
1234567894837376383439434343232
```

In the above scenario, i dont want to select the twelve digits. So the answer i think is to only select the twelve digits, if those twelve digits are not preceded or proceeded by other digits. I tried this change:

```
[^0-9]([12]\d{3})(\d{6})(\d{2})[^0-9]
```

This basically says get me the 12 digits only if the characters before and after the 12 digits are non numeric. The problem i have is i am also getting those non-numeric characters as part of the match i.e.

```
ABCD123456789483X7376383439434343232 returns D123456789483X
```

Is there anyway of checking what the preceding and proceeding characters are but not include them in the match result? i.e. only match if the preceding and proceeding characters are non numeric but don't include those non-numeric characters in the match result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lookarounds:

```
(?<!\\d)([12]\d{3})(\d{6})(\d{2})(?!\\d)
```

Here:

- `(?<!\\d)` is a negative lookbehind which means your pattern is not preceded by a digit
- `(?!\\d)` is a negative lookahead which means your pattern is not followed by a digit

#### [Read more about lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thanks - Do you mind explaining how or what that expression does.

Comment: Yes added my explanation and a very useful link to understand lookarounds.

Comment: No it is now picking. That regex site is not that great. See it working here: http://regex101.com/r/lS0aA0

Comment: Yes i noticed that - It was my mistake as i double escaped the digit - Thanks